# Retrieve stripe->refund->all limit

Tags: stripe-payments

I am trying to retrieve stripe -> refund -> all for certain period and it works, but I'm not getting more than 10 refunds as the default limit is 10 objects.

My question is: how to retrieve stripe -> refund -> all for more than 10 for specific period?

I have tried

```
$stripe_refunds = $this->stripe->refunds->all('created'=>['gte' => $date_from_unix, 'lte' => $date_to_unix]],['limit' => '100'],['stripe_account' => env('STRIPE_APP_CLIENT_ID')]);
```

but I am getting an error that says the limit is an expected in the query

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to paginate through the results. Stripe libraries support auto-pagination. To use the auto-pagination feature in PHP, simply issue an initial "list" call with the parameters you need, then call `autoPagingIterator()` on the returned list object to iterate over all objects matching your initial parameters. [0]

Example

```
$refunds = $stripe->refunds->all([
  'limit' => 10,
]);
foreach ($refunds->autoPagingIterator() as $refund) {
   // Do something with $refund
}
```

[0] https://stripe.com/docs/api/pagination/auto